# I passed the variable of Date type to Ajax and received it back to the controller, but the value changed

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, types

I want to receive the date through the date picker and put it in an object that stores reservation information(RentalPlacesVo).
I received the date from the reservation form and also confirmed that the controller fits the vo object well (even the datatype in rental_date was java.sql.Date)
After making the payment, I sent it to Ajax to include it with other information, and in the process of processing Ajax, I confirmed that 2022-07-23 was changed to 1992. It seems that the date has not been properly stored in the date type column of the db since the date has been changed to 1992.

I need to store data of DATE type on vo object, how can I get it?

Details of the error are as follows.

> WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam java.sql.Date] for value '1992'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

**RentalPlacesVo**

```
package com.joinus.domain;

import java.sql.Date;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class RentalPlacesVo {
    
    private int rental_places_no;
    private String reservation_no;
    private int club_no;
    private int member_no;
    private int partner_place_no;
    private int payment_no;
    private Date rental_date;
    private int rental_time_no;
    private int rental_status;
    
}
```

**reservationForm.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
    
<%@ include file="../include/header.jsp"%>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey="appkey"&libraries=services"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Calendar
    var config = {
            dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
            showOn : "button",
            buttonText : "선택",
            prevText : '이전 달',
            nextText : '다음 달',
            monthNames : ['1월','2월','3월','4월','5월','6월','7월','8월','9월','10월','11월','12월'],
            monthNamesShort : ['1월','2월','3월','4월','5월','6월','7월','8월','9월','10월','11월','12월'],
            dayNames : ['일','월','화','수','목','금','토'],
            dayNamesShort : ['일','월','화','수','목','금','토'],
            dayNamesMin : ['일','월','화','수','목','금','토'],
            yearSuffix : '년',
            minDate : 1
    }
    
    $(function(){
        $("input[name='rental_date']").datepicker(config);
    });
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        $(':button').attr('class','btn btn-primary');
        
        $('#subBtn').click(function(){
//          var date = $('#rental_date').val(); // 2022-07-23
            
            if($('#rental_date').val() == ''){
                $('#rental_date').focus();
                return false;
            }
            if($('#rental_time_no').val() == ''){
                $('#rental_time_no').focus();
                return false;
            }
            if($('#memberCnt').val() == ''){
                $('#memberCnt').focus();
                return false;
            }
            if($('#memberCnt').val() > 20){
                alert('Max MemberCnt : 20');
                $('#memberCnt').focus();
                return false;
            }

            
        });
        
    });


</script>

<div class="container-xxl py-5">
    <div class="container" style="color: black;">
        <div class="row g-5">
            <h1 id="partnerPlaceName">${partnerPlace.partner_place_name }</h1>
            
            <div style="width: 70%;">
                <img style="width: 95%; max-height: 550px;" src="${PageContext.request.contextPath }/resources/upload/partner_place/${partnerPlace.partner_place_image}">
                <div style="margin-top: 3em;">
                    <pre class="boardContent">${partnerPlace.partner_place_content }</pre>
                </div>
                
                <div style="margin-bottom: 16px;">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone-alt me-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>${partnerPlace.partner_place_tel }
                </div>
                <div id="partnerPlaceAddr" style="margin-bottom: 16px;">
                    ${partnerPlace.partner_place_address }
                </div>
                
            </div>
            

            <div style="width: 30%; border: 1px solid #32C36C; padding-top: 1em; height: 70%;">
                <form name="fr" action="" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="partner_place_no" value="${partner_place_no }">
                    <input type="hidden" name="partner_place_name" value="${partnerPlace.partner_place_name }">
                    <input type="hidden" name="partner_place_price" value="${partnerPlace.partner_place_price }">
                
                    <div>
                        <div style="font-size: x-large; float: left;">
                            ${partnerPlace.partner_place_name }
                        </div>
                        <div style="color: #32C36C; text-align: right; margin-bottom: 2em;">
                            <span style="font-size: x-large;">
                                <fmt:setLocale value="ko_KR"/><fmt:formatNumber type="currency" value="${partnerPlace.partner_place_price }" />
                                <br>
                            </span>
                            <span style="color: #9B9B9B;"> /hour</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    <div>
                    MemberCnt <input type="number" class="form-control" id="memberCnt" name="memberCnt" max="20" required>
                    </div>
                    
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var memberCnt = 0;
                        var totalPrice = 0;
                        $('#memberCnt').blur(function(){
                            memberCnt = $('#memberCnt').val();
                            totalPrice = memberCnt * ${partnerPlace.partner_place_price} * 2
                            document.getElementById("seePrice").innerHTML = totalPrice.toLocaleString();
                            $('#payment_price').val(totalPrice);
                            
                        });
                    </script>
                    
                    
                    <!-- Date -->
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 2em;">
                        Select Date (Click button)
                        <input class="form-control" id="rental_date" name="rental_date" autocomplete="off" readonly style="background-color: white;">
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- Time -->
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 2em;">
                        Time
                        <select class="form-select" id="rental_time_no" name="rental_time_no">
                            <option value="">Select Time</option>
                            <option value="1">10:00~12:00</option>
                            <option value="2">12:00~14:00</option>
                            <option value="3">14:00~16:00</option>
                            <option value="4">16:00~18:00</option>
                            <option value="5">18:00~20:00</option>
                            <option value="6">20:00~22:00</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <!--  TotalPrice -->
                    <div>
                        TotalPrice<br>
                        <span id="seePrice"></span>
                        <input type="hidden" id="payment_price" name="payment_price">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="payBtn">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill py-3 px-5" id="subBtn" value="pay">
                    </div>
                
                </form>
            </div>

            
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    
<%@ include file="../include/footer.jsp"%>
```

**Controller**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/partnerPlaces/{partner_place_no}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String partnerPlaceContentPost(PartnerPlacesVo partnerplacevo ,PaymentsVo paymentvo, 
            RentalPlacesVo rentalplacevo, Model model, @RequestParam("rental_time_no") int rentaltimeno,
            HttpSession session,@RequestParam("payment_price") int payment_price) {
        log.info(" partnerPlaceContentPost() 호출");
//      log.info("@@@@@rental_date : "+rental_date);    // 2022-07-23
        log.info("rentalplacevo : "+rentalplacevo.getRental_date());
        log.info("rental_date type: "+rentalplacevo.getRental_date().getClass().getName()); // java.sql.Date
        
        String ppname = partnerplacevo.getPartner_place_name();
        model.addAttribute("ppname", ppname);
        model.addAttribute("payment_price", payment_price);
        log.info("ppname, totalprice: "+ppname+payment_price);
        
        MembersVo vo = (MembersVo)session.getAttribute("member");
        model.addAttribute("members", vo);
        model.addAttribute("rental_time_no", rentaltimeno);
        model.addAttribute("payment", paymentvo);
        model.addAttribute("rentalplacevo", rentalplacevo);
        
        return "/rental/payment";
        
    }
```

**payment.jsp** (use API)

```
if(rsp.success){
    $.ajax({ //verify
        type : 'POST',
        url : '${PageContext.request.contextPath }/rental/verifyIamport/'+rsp.imp_uid 
    }).done(function(result){
        // rsp.paid_amount와 result.response.amount(서버 검증) 비교 후 로직 실행
            if(rsp.paid_amount === result.response.amount){
            alert("success pay varify"); console.log("success pay varify");
            var rental_date = ${rentalplacevo.rental_date};
            alert("rental_date : "+rental_date);    // 1992
            
                $.ajax({
                    url : '${PageContext.request.contextPath }/rental/partnerPlaces/'+${payment.partner_place_no}+'/payment', 
                    type :'POST',
                    data :{'partner_place_price':${payment.partner_place_price},
                        'rental_date':${rentalplacevo.rental_date},
                        'payment_price':${payment_price},
                        'rental_time_no':${rental_time_no}},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(paymentvo){
                         alert('Success store all data'); 
                         setTimeout(function(){
                             location.href="${PageContext.request.contextPath }/"
                         },5000);
                    }
                    });
                }
        
    }).fail(function(error){
            console.log("fail to store data"); 
    });
}else{
        alert('fail'+'errorCode : '+rsp.error_code+'errMsg : '+rsp.error_message);
    }
```

**Controller**  - I can't get over here.

```
        @ResponseBody
        @RequestMapping(value="/verifyIamport/{imp_uid}")
        public IamportResponse<Payment> paymentByImpUid(
                Model model, Locale locale, HttpSession session
                , @PathVariable("imp_uid") String imp_uid ) throws IamportResponseException, IOException{   
                log.info("paymentByImpUid");
                return api.paymentByImpUid(imp_uid);
                
        }
        
        @ResponseBody
        @RequestMapping(value ="/partnerPlaces/{partner_place_no}/payment",method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public PaymentsVo payment( Model model, 
                @RequestParam("partner_place_price") int partner_place_price,
                @RequestParam("rental_date") Date rental_date,
                @RequestParam("payment_price") int payment_price,
                @RequestParam("rental_time_no") int rental_time_no,
                @PathVariable("partner_place_no") int partner_place_no,
                RentalPlacesVo rentalplacevo, PaymentsVo paymentvo,HttpSession session){
            
            log.info("Vo Info . paymentvo : "+paymentvo);
            log.info("Vo Info . RentalPlacesVo : "+rentalplacevo);
            log.info("rental_date : "+rental_date);
//          log.info("rentdate dataType : "+rentdate.getClass().getName());
                
            // reservationNum (Date-place_no)
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            java.util.Date date = cal.getTime();
        
            String rsNum = sdf.format(date)+"-"+partner_place_no;
            log.info(reservationNum"+rsNum);
            
            paymentvo.setReservation_no(rsNum);
            MembersVo mvo = (MembersVo)session.getAttribute("member");
            paymentvo.setMember_no(mvo.getMember_no());
            paymentvo.setPartner_place_no(partner_place_no);
            paymentvo.setPartner_place_price(partner_place_price);
            paymentvo.setPayment_status(1);
            
            Integer pay = rentalService.pay(paymentvo);
            rentalplacevo.setPayment_no(paymentvo.getPayment_no());
            
            if(pay == 1) {
                log.info("success");
            }else {
                log.info("fail");
            }
    

            rentalplacevo.setClub_no(46);
            rentalplacevo.setMember_no(mvo.getMember_no());
            rentalplacevo.setRental_places_no(partner_place_no);
            rentalplacevo.setReservation_no(rsNum);
            rentalplacevo.setRental_date(rental_date);  // date
            rentalplacevo.setRental_time_no(rental_time_no);    // time
            rentalplacevo.setRental_status(1);
            
            rentalService.place(rentalplacevo);
            log.info("rentalPlace : "+rentalplacevo);
            
            
            return paymentvo;

            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use date related annotations on the date field.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) 
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd")
private Date rental_date;
```

Best practice:

Also it is recommended to use camel case standard for pojo entity class variables like **rentalDate**.

Comment: It didn't work even if I added an annotation, so I just saved the date and time information in vo before handing over the payment, loaded this vo after the payment, and saved the rest of the information.
Thank you for taking the time to answer. I tried to use the Carmel expression, but I tried to identify it with the table column name in the database, and the rule was broken.. Next time, I will refer to it and code it.